# Error in 'having' after 'group by ' clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, where-clause, having

I have the following sql query :

```
SELECT
     to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon') as mon,
     extract(year from p.log_date) as year,
from
     T
group by
     mon
having
     mon = 'september'
and
     year = '2018';
```

The table is in this format :

```
date        col1     col2
2018/09/10   --       --
2018/09/11   --       --
2018/09/12   --       --
```

T doesn't have the columns `mon` and `year`.
I am getting the error `ERROR:  column "mon" does not exist.` How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use where clause no need having

```
SELECT
     to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon') as mon,
     extract(year from p.log_date) as year from your_table
where  to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon') = 'september'
and
     extract(year from p.log_date) = '2018'
```

As there no aggregate function so don't think here `group by` need

and mon is your column alis name which is not find db engine in filter so its thrown error.

**Note: Not all dbms support alias name in filter(where or having)**

Answer (score 1):

Try below - this occured as you use alias name

```
SELECT
     to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon') as mon,
     extract(year from p.log_date) as year
where to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon')= 'september'
and year = '2018';
```

Comment: If I use a `where` clause before the `group by` clause, will there be any changes, performance/correctness wise?

Comment: It would be much more efficient.

Comment: @Jarvis in your case it would be better to use where clause as you are not filtering any aggregated value

Answer (score 1):

Using an alias in the `HAVING` clause causes the problem. You could use the `to_char` expression in the `HAVING` (or `WHERE` clause). But to avoid code replication you should do a subquery or a CTE:

```
SELECT
     mon,
     year,
     ...
FROM (
    SELECT 
        to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon') as mon, 
        extract(year from p.log_date) as year,
        ... 
    FROM ...
)s
group by
     mon
having
     mon = 'september'
and
     year = '2018';
```

CTE:

```
WITH my_sub_query AS (
    SELECT 
        to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon') as mon, 
        extract(year from p.log_date) as year,
        ... 
    FROM ...
)
SELECT
     mon,
     year,
     ...
FROM my_sub_query
group by
     mon
having
     mon = 'september'
and
     year = '2018';
```

---

Furthermore:

1. Try to use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`
2. To group by month and year you could do `date_trunc('month', p.log_date)` instead of `to_char` and `extract`

Answer (score 1):

`Having` used on aggregate function condition, but you don't need to use it because `to_char` and `extract` are normal function.

I think you forget to use `FROM` clause to select your table.

```
SELECT
     to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon') as mon,
     extract(year from p.log_date) as year,
FROM T
WHERE 
    to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon') = 'september'
AND
    extract(year from p.log_date) = '2018';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, Try this.

```
Select mon, [year] from (
  SELECT
     to_char(p.log_date, 'Mon') as mon,
     extract(year from p.log_date) as year,
 from T

) as DerivedTable

 where  mon = 'september' and  year = '2018'

group by mon
```